# assigning from a pointer value

Tags: c, pointers

I saw the following piece of code in an opensource AAC decoder,

```
static void flt_round(float32_t *pf)
{
    int32_t flg;
    uint32_t tmp, tmp1, tmp2;

    tmp = *(uint32_t*)pf;
    flg = tmp & (uint32_t)0x00008000;
    tmp &= (uint32_t)0xffff0000;
    tmp1 = tmp;
    /* round 1/2 lsb toward infinity */
    if (flg)
    {
        tmp &= (uint32_t)0xff800000;       /* extract exponent and sign */
        tmp |= (uint32_t)0x00010000;       /* insert 1 lsb */
        tmp2 = tmp;                             /* add 1 lsb and elided one */
        tmp &= (uint32_t)0xff800000;       /* extract exponent and sign */

        *pf = *(float32_t*)&tmp1 + *(float32_t*)&tmp2 - *(float32_t*)&tmp;
    } else {
        *pf = *(float32_t*)&tmp;
    }
}
```

In that the line,

```
*pf = *(float32_t*)&tmp;
```

is same as,

```
*pf = (float32_t)tmp;
```

Isn't it?

Or is there a difference? Maybe in performance?

Thank you.

Comment: tmp is not a `float32_t` and I think casting it will change the way it's handled by the program, while casting its address to a pointer to `float32_t` will ensure the program reads the value as-is

Comment: There is [an easy way](http://ideone.com/Xa0DqJ) to determine whether they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're completely different. Say the value of `tmp` is 1. Their code will give `*pf` the value of whatever floating point number has the same binary representation as the integer 1. Your code would give it the floating point value 1.0!

Comment: Thanks.. but it gives a "warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer" compiler warning. How can i correct it?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways. One way would be to use a union.

Comment: float32_t p;  memcpy(&p, &tmp, sizeof(float32_t)); is correct, isnt it? where tmp is the variable in the example i have posted.

Comment: They are also different because the form used in the question has a bug which invokes undefined behavior. So "their code" will do anything, it might as well crash and burn as giving the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

This code is editing the value of a float knowing it is formatted using the [standard IEEE 754 floating representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

```
*(float32_t*)&tmp;
```

means reinterpret the address of temp as being a pointer on a 32 bit float, extract the value pointed.

```
(float32_t)tmp;
```

means cast the integer to float 32. Which means `32.1111f` may well produce `32`.

Answer (score 0):

Very different.
The first causes the bit pattern of `tmp` to be reinterpreted as a `float`.
The second causes the numerical value of `tmp` to be converted to `float` (within the accuracy that it can be represented including rounding).

Try this:

```
int main(void) {
    int32_t n=1078530011;

    float32_t f;

    f=*(float32_t*)(&n);
    printf("reinterpet the bit pattern of %d as float - f==%f\n",n,f);

    f=(float32_t)n;
    printf("cast the numerical value of %d as float  - f==%f\n",n,f);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
reinterpet the bit pattern of 1078530011 as float - f==3.141593
cast the numerical value of 1078530011 as float  - f==1078530048.000000
```

It's like thinking that

```
const char* str="3568";
int a=*(int*)str;
int b=atoi(str);
```

Will assign `a` and `b` the same values.

Answer (score 0):

First to answer the question, `my_float = (float)my_int` safely *converts* the integer to a float according to the rules of the standard (6.3.1.4).

> When a value of integer type is converted to a real floating type, if
>   the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type,
>   it is unchanged. If the value being converted is in the range of
>   values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the
>   result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable
>   value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. If the value being
>   converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the
>   behavior is undefined.

`my_float = *(float*)&my_int` on the other hand, is a dirty trick, telling the program that the binary contents of the integer should be treated as if they were a float variable, with no concerns at all.

*However*, the person who wrote the dirty trick was probably not aware of it leading to undefined behavior for another reason: it violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

To fix this bug, you either have to tell your compiler to behave in a non-standard, non-portable manner (for example gcc -fno-strict-aliasing), which I don't recommend.

Or preferably, you rewrite the code so that it doesn't rely on undefined behavior. Best way is to use unions, for which strict aliasing doesn't apply, in the following manner:

```
typedef union
{
  uint32_t  as_int;
  float32_t as_float;
} converter_t;

uint32_t value1, value2, value3; // do something with these variables

*pf = (converter_t){value1}.as_float + 
      (converter_t){value2}.as_float - 
      (converter_t){value3}.as_float;
```

Also it is good practice to add the following sanity check:

```
static_assert(sizeof(converter_t) == sizeof(uint32_t), 
              "Unexpected padding or wrong type sizes!");
```